# cuSparse Throughput goes down when number of iterations increases

Tags: c++, matrix, cuda, gpu, nvidia

I am trying to calculate the maximum throughput possible for my GPU for sprase matrix * dense vector multiplication by utilizing as many compute resources as possible.

In order to accomplish this I tried two methods:

1. Allocate memory for x and A on host. Store x and A on host. Allocate memory for x and A on device. Store x and A on device. Start timer. Perform sparse matrix*dense vector multiplication via cusparsecsrmv in a loop, and run cusparsecsrmv for NUM_ITERATIONS times. Stop timer. Copy y from device to host and check result for accuracy.
2. Allocate memory for x and A on host. Store x and A on host. Allocate memory for an array of x and A on device (i.e. x[NUM_IMPS], A[NUM_IMPS]). Store X and A on device. Start timer. Perform sparse matrix*dense vector multiplication via cusparsecsrmv in a loop, and run cusparsecsrmv for NUM_IMPS times on each A[i]*x[i]. Stop timer. Copy y[NUM_IMPS-1] from device to host and check result for accuracy.

Here is my code for method 1:

```
// == Start timer for just measuring multiplication == 
QueryPerformanceFrequency(&Frequency1); 
QueryPerformanceCounter(&StartingTime1); 


// Sparse matrix * dense vector multiplication 
/* exercise Level 2 routines (csrmv) */ 
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ITERATIONS; i++) { 
status = cusparseScsrmv(handle, CUSPARSE_OPERATION_NON_TRANSPOSE, m, n, nnz, 
&alpha, descr, cooVal, csrRowPtr, cooColIndex, 
&xVal[0], &beta, &y[0]); 
} 

// == End time for just measuring multiplication == 
QueryPerformanceCounter(&EndingTime1); 
ElapsedMicroseconds1.QuadPart = EndingTime1.QuadPart - StartingTime1.QuadPart; 
ElapsedMicroseconds1.QuadPart *= 1000000; 
ElapsedMicroseconds1.QuadPart /= Frequency1.QuadPart;
```

Here is my code for method 2:

```
// == Start timer for just measuring multiplication ==
QueryPerformanceFrequency(&Frequency1);
QueryPerformanceCounter(&StartingTime1);

for (int i = 0; i < NUM_IMPS; i++) {
status = cusparseScsrmv(handle_array[i], CUSPARSE_OPERATION_NON_TRANSPOSE, m, n, nnz,
    &alpha, descr_array[i], cooVal_array[i], csrRowPtr_array[i], cooColIndex_array[i],
    &xVal_array[i][0], &beta, &y_array[i][0]);
}

// == End time for just measuring multiplication ==
QueryPerformanceCounter(&EndingTime1);
ElapsedMicroseconds1.QuadPart = EndingTime1.QuadPart - StartingTime1.QuadPart;
ElapsedMicroseconds1.QuadPart *= 1000000;
ElapsedMicroseconds1.QuadPart /= Frequency1.QuadPart;
```

If NUM_ITERATIONS or NUM_IMPS = 1, they get the same throughput. 
If NUM_IMPS = 10, throughput maxes out. However once NUM_IMPS = 100 or more, throughput starts to decrease.
Similarly with NUM_ITERATIONS it starts to increase, but once I set NUM_ITERATIONS to a super large number, say 100,000 throughput will drop below the throughput for NUM_ITERATIONS = 1.

**Why this is happening?** I would expect thorughput to just saturate at some point and not be able to go any higher, *but not decrease.*

My thoughts are due to something with multiple calls to cusparsecsrmv that the GPU bogs down, or perhaps the GPU needs to cool itself down so it slows down, so throughput goes down, but these all don't seem like reasonable conclusions to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting from the [documentation:](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusparse/#asynchronous-execution)

> The cuSPARSE library functions are executed asynchronously with
>   respect to the host and may return control to the application on the
>   host before the result is ready. Developers can use the
>   cudaDeviceSynchronize() function to ensure that the execution of a
>   particular cuSPARSE library routine has completed.

There is nothing wrong here except the way you are timing. At present you are only measuring the time to enqueue the library calls, not the time to run them. It is perfectly reasonable to expect that the enqueue performance would drop once you have  many tens or hundreds of operations queued up.

Comment: What is the correct way to measure timing? Add a cudaDeviceSynchronize() command right after after all of the calls? I did that and the performance tanked, much lower than I expected.

Comment: The performance didn't "tank". You just started measuring it correctly.

Comment: so how many iterations do you think i should run before I run cudaDeviceSynchronize? Also, do I just run cudaDeviceSynchronize with no arguments?

Comment: There is no answer to that first question. And yes synchronisation had no arguments. It seems like you need to read some documentation